# Dapper insert a list?

Tags: .net, dapper

I want to do a bulk insert. A is an ID and B is a list of IDs. My insert statement looks like this but it is wrong. How do I rewrite it to work? The only solution I can think of is using a foreach loop outside the statement

```
.Execute(@"insert into MyTable(a,b) select @a, @b", new {a, b})
```

Comment: It looks like there might be a bulk insert int some extension methods: https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/issues/18

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
var abs = b.Select(id => new { a, b = id });
int numInserted = connection
    .Execute(@"insert into MyTable(a,b) VALUES(@a, @b)", abs);
```

Comment: Here I was thinking I should rewrite the statement. That works. Accepted

Comment: On second thought the for loop might be cleaner but I'll leave it as is