# Inserting a list into temp table using Dapper

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net, dapper

I am trying to insert a List of integers into a temporary table using Dapper. I wrote my query based on the selected answer to this Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44003428/insert-a-list-using-dapper-net-c-sharp). However, I get a syntax error when running the query.

**Code:**

```
List<int> lst = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4};
string queryString="CREATE TABLE #Temp (ListInt int)" 
                + " INSERT INTO #Temp (ListInt) VALUES (@Lst);";
dbConnection.Open();

dbConnection.Query(queryString, new {Lst = lst});
```

**Error:**

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

How can I use Dapper to insert this list?

Comment: What is 'lst'  in your code? Provide a minimal and complete example

Comment: lst is a List<Int>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this via Dapper's [Execute a Command multiple times](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper#execute-a-command-multiple-times) feature.

The SQL query must contain *only* the command you want repeated, and the parameters (passed to Dapper) must be an `IEnumerable` of objects where each object has a property named after the parameter you're using. Finally, use `Execute` (not `Query`) when you're inserting (not retrieving) values:

```
List<int> lst = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4};
dbConnection.Open();
dbConnection.Execute("CREATE TABLE #Temp (ListInt int)");
dbConnection.Execute("INSERT INTO #Temp (ListInt) VALUES (@item);",
    lst.Select(x => new { item = x }));
```

Note that if you're inserting thousands of items, the `INSERT` statement will be executed once per item, which can be very slow. If this is the case, investigate a community extension to Dapper, such as [BulkInsert](https://faithlife.github.io/DapperUtility/BulkInsert.html) that can insert 1000s of items in one `INSERT` statement.